# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "de perdidos al río"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, españa

En el diccionario de la lengua se [recoge](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WUyYSwW):

> **de perdidos al río**
>
> 1. expr. coloq. U. para expresar que una vez empezada una acción hay que aceptar todas las consecuencias y procurar llevarla a término.

¿De dónde procede esta expresión?

Comment: Sería bueno poner una etiqueta de región o país a esta pregunta. Por mi tierrita jamás la he oído.

Comment: Veamos... De perdidos al río viene de cuando andas perdido/a explorando una zona, vuelves al río para orientarte. ¡Punto pelota!

Answer (score 3):

El [Centro Virtual Cervantes](http://cvc.cervantes.es) tiene un [refranero multilingüe](http://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/Default.aspx) que, al respecto de este refrán, dice [lo siguiente](http://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/ficha.aspx?Par=58474&Lng=0):

> Se emplea para indicar que, ante una situación muy difícil, se opta por la solución más descabellada, en este caso representada por la decisión de tirarse al río, por ejemplo, ante el avance del enemigo o un fuego.

Y como explicación, postula la siguiente:

> Parece que esta frase proviene de las batallas, cuando en otros tiempos la principal maniobra para derrotar al enemigo consistía en empujarlo hasta que llegase a orillas del río. Así, al tener a su espalda el río, se reduciría su capacidad de maniobra y perdería la batalla, pues o se tiraban al río si no querían morir o se rendían.

Comment: Lo que puede estar relacionado con la expresión _a enemigo que huye, puente de plata_.

Comment: ¿La usan en España? Jamás la había oído.

Comment: @DGaleano aquí en España se usa bastante, incluyendo la versión cómica _from lost to the river_.

Comment: A mi se me parece a una que usamos aquí que es `saltar del caldero[de la olla] al fuego`