# ¿De dónde viene lo de "darse con un canto en los dientes"?

Tags: etimología, modismos, expresiones

[**Darse con un canto en los dientes, en los nudillos, o en los pechos**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7DCRVC3) es

> 1. locs. verbs. coloqs. Darse por contento cuando lo que ocurre es más favorable o menos adverso de lo que podía esperarse.

¿De dónde viene la expresión?

Comment: Felix: parece que tienes experiencia en el sitio y [ayer preguntaste](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21191/1674) con el mismo nombre de usuario. Puedes leer [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: @fedorqui así decía yo que me sonaba el usuario...

Answer (score 2):

La expresión es muy curiosa, y parece que originalmente se decía *darse con un canto en los pechos* (entendiéndose *canto* como *piedra*), tal y como registra el DLE allá por 1889:

> **Darse** uno **con un canto en los pechos**. fr. fig. y fam. Darse por contento, cuando lo que ocurre es más faborable ó menos adverso de lo que podía esperarse.

Como ves, la definición no ha variado mucho desde entonces. Bastante más antigua es, sin embargo, esta otra que es prima hermana y que ya aparece en la segunda edición del DLE, de 1780:

> **Con un canto a los pechos**. expr. fam. Con mucho gusto y complacencia.

Según parece, todo proviene de antiguos ritos de mortificación llevados a cabo por los cristianos. El texto más significativo que he encontrado que lo demuestra es este (negritas mías):

> *[...] y es que los que comen suelen pedir licencia para echar un poco de ceniza en lo que comen. Y esta licencia la pide, en nombre del que come, habiéndoselo así dicho, el servidor. Y dándola el prelado, va y llévele el plato de ceniza que está en la mesa traviesa y con una cucharilla echa en el manjar y comida lo que Dios le da a entender. Confieso que para esta mortificación no he dado licencia de buena gana, porque esto suele ser enfermo por ser cosa muy fuerte la ceniza y poderle en la garganta hacer alguna llaga o en las tripas. Pueden usar de otras en lugar de ésta, como es no comer vinagre ni sal en tantos días o pedir licencia para destemplar y quitar el gusto al manjar con una poca de agua fría.
>
>   Para el refectorio paréceme bastan estas mortificaciones, sin hacer en éstas o en otras semejantes ningún género de estremo. Algunas veces se ha hecho en nuestro refectorio y fuera de él una mortificación de **darse con un canto en los pechos**, y ésta me parece muy justo que no se consienta más, por el daño que puede hacer a la tal persona; y los que lo ven no se edifican, sino reciben pena y notable disgusto.*
>
> San Juan Bautista de la Concepción (Juan García Gómez), "De los oficios más comunes", c. 1607 (España).

Fíjate que en el siglo XVII ya se consideraba esta mortificación (que, recordemos, significa en este contexto "domar las pasiones castigando el cuerpo y refrenando la voluntad") como algo excesivo. Posiblemente por ser algo excesivo pasó a formar parte del habla coloquial, dado lo mucho que nos gustan las exageraciones en España. Es fácil entender cómo la expresión pasó primero a significar "hacer algo con gusto", como indicando que a pesar de ser una mortificación excesiva se hace con complacencia por el bien que te produce, y posteriormente a usarse para decir que debes mortificarte de esa forma para alejar los malos pensamientos que te puedan originar algo que ha sucedido, pero que no es tan malo como piensas.

Es curioso que ya por aquel siglo XVII se usaba medio en serio medio figuradamente, aunque no pasara al diccionario hasta bastante más tarde, tal y como lo demuestra este otro texto:

> *No sé cómo podremos sacar a mi hermano y volver a mi alma a su casa. Mal haya el diablo, a fe que **se podría Cervino dar con un canto en los pechos** antes que me sacara la presa de las manos, a no tener tal prenda... en su casa. ¡Oh, qué terrible cosa es haber por fuerza de refrenar el apetito y gusto, y privarse de su contento!*
>
> Diego Alfonso Velásquez de Velasco, "El celoso", 1602 (España).

Las variantes de darse en los nudillos o en los dientes son posteriores. Concretamente, en el CORDE los primeros casos de esta última se dan ya entrado el siglo XX, entrando dichas variantes en el DLE en la edición de 1970. Veamos un ejemplo:

> *A veces, el que rabia por cantar, porque rabia, cruje, rechina los dientes, como si estuviera condenado. El rechinar de dientes es una música infernal poética. Un estremecimiento siempre nuevo (temor divino o terror pánico) es lo que alarga los dientes, haciéndolos crujir de ese modo. Baudelaire se creía condenado para eso: para poder cantar entre dientes, rechinándolos como un condenado. No ahínca sus dientes blancos en las cosas el pensamiento -su hambre ideal de cosa, su ansia de realidad-, sin antes sentirse condenado: hondo, hueco, vacío. Y canta. O es canto el eco de su rabiosa poesía cuando se da, porque se da, **con un canto en los dientes**.*
>
> José Bergamín, "Artículos", 1923-1974 (España).

Supongo que "darse en los pechos" quedó un poco anticuado y se buscaron otras formas mucho más expresivas.

Comment: @walen o incluso como "borde", "extremidad", "grosor de algo": cuando se dice "ha faltado el canto de un duro" se refiere a que ha faltado muy poco (el grosor de una moneda de cinco pesetas). Se podría estar dando en los dientes con el canto (filo, borde) de un cuchillo, por ejemplo.